# Recursive Linear Search

Tags: algorithm, recursion, return, linear-search

The code shown below works fine. It prints the position of the element found inside the if clause and exits. Whenever the element is not found, the function runs to max and returns 0 to calling function to indicate no elements has been found.

However, I was pondering about returning the position of the element found, to the calling function rather than printing it. Since returning the position would just return to earlier instance of the function and not to the calling function, I am struck. How to achieve this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int RLinearSearch(int A[],int n,int key)
{
    if(n<1)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        RLinearSearch(A,n-1,key);
        if(A[n-1]==key)
        {
            printf("found %d at %d",key,n);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int A[5]={23,41,22,15,32};   // Array Of 5 Elements 
    int pos,n=5;

    pos=RLinearSearch(A,n,23);

    if(pos==0)
        printf("Not found");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since returning the position would just return to earlier instance of the function and not to the calling function, I am struck.

You can solve this problem by returning the result of recursive invocation from the recursive call itself:

```
int RLinearSearch(int A[], int n, int key) {
    if(n<0) { // Base case - not found
        return -1;
    }
    if(A[n]==key) { // Base case - found
        return n;
    }
    // Recursive case
    return RLinearSearch(A, n-1, key);
}
```

Since this implementation treats `n` as the index of the current element, the caller should pass 4, not 5, in your example.

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/Q8e3Jp)

**Note:** you can further simplify the code by joining the base cases together:

```
int RLinearSearch(int A[], int n, int key) {
    return (n<0 || A[n]==key) ? n : RLinearSearch(A, n-1, key);
}
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/RXcnIn)

Comment: So this basically finds the first occurrence of the element from right to left of the array. Once the first occurrence is found, the function doesn't look any further?

Comment: @geek_code That's correct, since the function can return only one item, the first item on the right is returned.

Comment: I Appreciate your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the function used in this answer would return the length of the array if you specify the key to be the first element(expected result to be 0)

Comment: @CSBigSur not really: the function correctly returns zero when the searched element is in the initial position of the array ([demo](https://ideone.com/DncbNF)).

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code? [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/E7SDKmk)

Comment: @CSBigSur Yes, you should not be passing `size()` into the call for `n`, because it's the index of one-past-the-last-element; you want `size()-1`, but only after checking that the vector is not empty. You should also avoid passing `std::vector` by value: use `const` reference instead. Note that it is not a problem for arrays, because they "decay" to a pointer. A vector, on the other hand, will be copied, making the search really slow.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I was... unconscious.

Answer (score 1):

start with your problem: linear search returning the index of where the key is found the function has three perameters, the array, the starting index of search n and the search key k.

so you have:

```
int RLinearSearch(int[] A, int n, int k) 
{    
    if (n=>A.length()) return (-1);//base case(k not found in A)
    else if (A[n]==k) return n; //found case
    else return RLinearSearch(A, n+1, key); //continue case(keep looking through array)
}
int main(void){
    int A[5]={23,41,22,15,32};   // Array Of 5 Elements 
    int pos,n=0;

    pos=RLinearSearch(A,n,23);
    if (pos == -1) printf("Not Found");
    return 0;
}
```

you could also change it so that you just returned n-1 and you would have the right index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tail recursion :

```
int LSearch(int a[],int n,int key,int i)
 {
  if(n==0) return -1;
  if(a[0]==key) return i;
  LSearch(a+1,n-1,key,++i);
 }
```

while calling use the function call:

```
LSeacrh(a,n,key,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int recursiveLinearSearch(int[] data, int index, int key){
    
    if(index==data.length)
        return -1;
    if(data[index]==key)
        return index;
    
    return recursiveLinearSearch(data, index+1, key);
    
}
```